# SetWindowsHookEx function in MAC os

Tags: macos-sierra, kernel32, setwindowshookex

Am facing run-time error 53: filenot found kernel32 when i tested in MAC machine.

Am using SetWindowsHookEx function written in VB script for excel macros.

Since SetWindowsHookEx is a windows func, am facing this error. Is there any alternative to this function in MAC OS.
I have least ideas about MAC OS

Comment: Wine Is Not an Emulator

Comment: Didn't get you, is there any replacement for this function ? setWindowsHookEx in MAC OS

Comment: Wine is a famous Windows environment for Unix systems.

Comment: any replacement for this function ? setWindowsHookEx in MAC OS ?

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx is for receiving mouse, keyboard and other os events. The equivalent on macOS is the Responder chain, the NSResponder class and strictly speaking the setNextResponder: selector would be the equivalent.  However in the context you wish to use them, Excel VB Macros, you are not going to simply be able to replace the SetWindowsHookEx with setNextResponder.  You are dealing with low level OS events and if you want to run the macro on both platforms you should look at rewriting it without SetWindowsHookEx.